# Defining a function with string.replace within a class

Tags: python

I have defined a class "DNA". I am now trying to create a function within that class that will allow me to translate DNA to RNA (which bascially means replacing any "T" with "U"). My DNA class has inherited parameters from another class.
I have to use the string.replace method.

```
class DNA(Seq):
   def __init__(self, seq):
    Seq.__init__(self, seq, pattern=(re.compile('[^ACGTacgt]')))
    self.data = seq.upper()
def __repr__(self):
        return self.data
```

I want to use the function on a dna-sequence of the DNA class.

Edit:
I want to be able to do the following:

```
dna1 = DNA('ACCCGT')
rna1 = dna1.translate_to_RNA()
print rna1
```

Where the translate_to_RNA() is my defined function and the output would be ('ACCCGU')

Edit2:

```
class Seq:
    def __init__(self, seq, pattern): 
        if pattern.search(seq): 
            print " Warning : sequence contains illegal characters " 
        self.data = seq.upper() 
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data[index]
    def __len__(self):  
        return len(self.data) 

import re

class DNA(Seq):
    def __init__(self, seq):
        Seq.__init__(self, seq, pattern=(re.compile('[^ACGTacgt]')))
        self.data = seq.upper()
        self.seq = seq
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.data
    def translate_to_RNA(self):
        new_string = self.seq("T","U")
        rna1 = RNA(new_string)
        return rna1


class RNA(Seq):
    def __init__(self, seq):
        Seq.__init__(self, seq, pattern=(re.compile('[^ACGUacgu]')))
        self.data = seq.upper()
    def __repr__(self):
            return self.data
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation for string.replace? That function will do everything you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a method within you use the string.replace() method on the string that represents the data. (You didn't explain how this data was represented).

Edition:
You should use a string variable in the DNA class that will save the string you initialize the DNA instance with. you should define a similar RNA class.
then, you can implement a function in the DNA class like this:

```
def translate(self):
    new_string=self.string_representation.replace("T","U")
    rna1 = RNA(new_string)
    return rna1
```

as for the print operator, you need to implement a string cast for you RNA class. (using **str**)

Comment: I already have a similar class for RNA defined. I am sorry for aksing as a novice, but what should i put instead of string_representation? (my editor is giving me an attribute error: DNA instance has no attribute 'string_representation'.

Comment: you should create it in the __init__ method, and put the string parameter inside it.

Comment: I am sorry that I am having so many troubles understanding you. I am sure your answer is correct, but I cannot get it to work. I have posted my entire code. If you could elaborate on your soultion it would be great. If I am missing any fundemental knowledge, please let me know.

Comment: self.seq("T","U") should be self.seq.replace("T","U")

Comment: Thank you soooo much!!! This have taking me ages! I cannot upvote you as my profile is new, but you really helped me!